# I have got an error when downloading android sdk

Tags: android, sdk

hi i downloded android studio 3.1.2 and installed it but the gradle did not syncronise. i have tried to fix it but i couldn't, then i uninsttalled the android studio and deleted all things about it like sdk ... after that i have reinstalled the android studio and want to download sdk manager , when downloding start i have got those errors and i have attached the picture: [Downloading components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua9VL.png)

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4623001.zip': 
SSL peer shut down incorrectly ,
 response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: 
Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4623001.zip': 
SSL peer shut down incorrectly ,
 response: 200 OK. 
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.1.12)" failed. Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
 Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip java.io.IOException: 
Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Unexpected end of file from server ,
 response: 200 OK Warning: 
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository:
 Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': 
Unexpected end of file from server ,
 response: 200 OK.
```

Comment: This might be the wrong site for this question/off topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

1. Go to Build --> Clean Project.
2. Go to SDK Manager and try to download again.